# setTheme colorprimary not working as background in custom toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I have a custom toolbar that I just added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

notice that I set background as colorPrimary.

In style.xml I have 2 styles:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Yellow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ffff00</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>
    </style>
```

my color.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000</color>
</resources>
```

I change color in activity using setTheme:

```
setTheme(colorId);
```

it works, except the BACKGROUND color that is always black, even if I set setTheme as Yellow.

any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is overriding the background color of Toolbar

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

. 
Remove android:theme attribute from Toolbar then it will work.

To change textcolor follow the below code:

```
<style name="CustomTextColor" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">Your Text Color</item>
</style>
```

Now set the theme to your Toolbar:

```
app:theme="@style/CustomTextColor"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much! but removing this my toolbar text will be black, how could I set it as white?

Comment: You can add a custom theme to your Toolbar where you can define Toolbar textcolor. I'll add the code in a bit if you like.